# Soft edges (fade in) on a copied part of an image

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, bmp

**The title may be very unclear but I have no idea on how to state it differently.**

I have a working project -that copies one part of an image to another. Like so:

[image]

I achieved this using the following:

```
      procedure TForm1.StampCircle;
var
  DstRect, SrcRect: TRect;
  x, y: Integer;
  MyRgn: HRGN;
begin
  x := shp_Dragger.Left;
  y := shp_Dragger.Top;

  MyRgn := CreateEllipticRGN(shp_Dragger.Left, shp_Dragger.Top, shp_Dragger.Left + shp_Dragger.Width, shp_Dragger.Top + shp_Dragger.Height);
  SelectClipRgn(Img1.Canvas.Handle, MyRgn);

  with Img1.Canvas do
  begin
    CopyMode := cmSrcCopy;
    SrcRect := Rect(Shape_Start_x, Shape_Start_y, Shape_End_x, Shape_End_y);
    DstRect := Rect(shp_Dragger.Left, shp_Dragger.Top, shp_Dragger.Left + shp_Dragger.Width, shp_Dragger.Top + shp_Dragger.Height);
    CopyRect(DstRect, Img1.Canvas, SrcRect);
  end;

  Img1.Invalidate;
  SelectClipRgn(Img1.Canvas.Handle, HRGN(nil));
  DeleteObject(MyRgn);

end;
```

The problem is that is not 100% what it needs to do.

It needs to have soft edges (that fades in).
It needs to look something like this[image]

**NOTE** The image is converted from a JPEG to a BMP when it is first loaded.

```
procedure TForm1.LoadAndConvertToBMP(FilePath: WideString);
var
  OleGraphic: TOleGraphic;
  fs: TFileStream;
  Source: TImage;
begin
  try
    OleGraphic := TOleGraphic.Create; {The magic class!}

    fs := TFileStream.Create(FilePath, fmOpenRead or fmSharedenyNone);
    OleGraphic.LoadFromStream(fs);

    Source := Timage.Create(Nil);
    Source.Picture.Assign(OleGraphic);

    bmp := TBitmap.Create; {Converting to Bitmap}
    bmp.Width := Source.Picture.Width;
    bmp.Height := source.Picture.Height;
    bmp.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, source.Picture.Graphic);

    img1.Picture.Bitmap := BMP; {Show the bitmap on form}
  finally
    fs.Free;
    OleGraphic.Free;
    Source.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I saw a lot of ideas online, and I tried a lot of different approaches, but none of them worked effectively.

I would really appreciate any help or direction i.e. where to look or what to try.

Thank you

Comment: Draw a circle over the pasted picture. With pure GDI you won't get such result (maybe with GDI+). Still, libraries like [Graphics32](https://github.com/graphics32), or [AGG](https://github.com/CWBudde/AggPasMod) can help you with a drawing application.

Comment: Old, but maybe still useful: http://www.efg2.com/Lab/ImageProcessing/Feathering.htm. Such soft edges are often called feathered edges. Perhaps that term can help you find more info.